# Pi-Hole with two gateways?

Tags: pi-3, pi-hole

Heres my problem.  I have a Raspberrypi running pi-hole through router a.  I have a second router running openvpn as a tunnel, router "b".  I would like to have the pi-hole ad-protect both networks.

Router "a" is 192.168.1.1 and the router "b" is 192.168.2.1

any help would be great.

Comment: How are "a" and "b" connected to each other?

Comment: Router B is attached over eth0 to Router A.  I have a bridge setup on Router B as gateway with openvpn running NORDVPN for encryption.  Essentially I want the pi-hole to filter the bridge

Comment: You should just be able to set "b" to look up the DNS from the address of the Pi. Since it is connected to "a" it should also have an address of 192.168.1.x/24 on the side that faces both "a" and the Pi and 192.168.2.1/24 on the other side.

Comment: I see your point, and that works, but I believe I am going about this incorrectly.  Since the pi-hole includes the other router as 192.168.1.30, it doesn’t see the incoming packets from the bridge created on eth0 on the device.  I guess my question should be how to include the tunnel on router B.

Comment: okay, you are correct, I didn’t believe that the openvpn dns would work if I changed it to the pi-hole, but after multiple tests it does, so now i have what I wanted, VPN encrypted gateway using one Rasp as pi-hole and the other Rasp as a VPN router gateway.  Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1):

To summarize my questions and your responses above, here is a network diagram:

[image: Network Configuration]

Router B is connected to Router A, and therefore has an address on the 192.168.1.0/24 network. Router A is 192.168.1.1. The Pi-hole is 192.168.1.30.

To get Router B to use the Pi-hole to filter any DNS request to block unwanted content, Router B just needs to be configured to use 192.168.1.30 as its primary (and only) DNS lookup. With both routers A and B set to use that address for DNS, both 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24 networks have the DNS filtering.